# Canonical way to define and execute a method that outputs Unit?

Tags: scala

I have a list of methods (functions) that output `Unit`:

```
var fns:List[() => Unit] = Nil
def add(fn:() => Unit) = fns :+= fn      // a method to add to the list
```

I want to add `println("hello")` to the list.

```
add(() => println("hello"))
```

Is there a better way than using the ugly parenthesis.

I would have preferred:

```
add (println("hello"))  // error here 

def myCoolMethod = {
   // do something cool
   // may return something, not necessarily Unit
}
add (myCoolMethod) // error here
```

I tried `var fns:List[_ => Unit]` and `var fns:List[Any => Unit]`, `fns:List[() => Any]`, etc without getting what I want.

Second question is how do I execute the methods in the list when I want to. I got it to work with:

```
fns foreach (_.apply)
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `by-name` parameter instead of function with empty parameters list like this:

```
var fns:List[() => Unit] = Nil
def add(fn: => Unit) = fns :+= (fn _)

add{ print("hello ") }

def myCoolMethod = { println("world") }
add(myCoolMethod)

fns foreach {_.apply}
// hello world
```

You could use `_()` instead of `_.apply`: `fns foreach {_()}`, but I'd prefer `_.apply`.

Comment: Can we have an `add` that accepts a `Seq` of methods rather than one method? So I could do `add(Seq(println("hello "), myCoolMethod))`.

Comment: @Jus12: no, you can't get repeated by-name parameters without macros.